# Change x-axis on FacetGrid or set limits on fill_between

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have copied the [RidgePlot example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot) and adopted it to my needs. I have included the working script and some example data to test.

Image:
[image]

Some of my data have y-values equal to 0.0. I would like to emphasise that in my plot. I'm not sure which part of the plot, the `fill_between` or just every x-axis can be changed to for example remove the mapped colour on those places where `"aandeel" == 0.0`.

Any ideas on how to remove the colours here? Is it simply possible to remove the x-axes/set width to 0/change color to different?

example data (csv): https://gist.github.com/willemvanopstal/c2892e68d6eb94194acd371e49d949bd

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np


sns.set(style="whitegrid", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})
data = pd.read_csv('stats_together_data.csv', delimiter=';')
df = data

# Initialize the FacetGrid object
pal = sns.color_palette("Set2")
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="process", hue="process", aspect=10, height=0.6, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.lineplot, "region", "aandeel", clip_on=False, alpha=1, lw=1.5)
g.map(plt.fill_between, "region", "aandeel", interpolate=True)
g.map(sns.lineplot, "region", "aandeel", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2)
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=1, clip_on=False)


# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)


g.map(label, "region")

# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.set(xticks=df.region[0::1])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would replace the 0.0 values with NaN. But that's not sufficient because a large part of your problem is the horizontal lines that are added to replace the bottom spine that hides the fact that the curves stop at different point. If you remove those, then you're left with:

[image]

Personally, I'm not overly found of the tick white line that makes the narrow regions on the left and right very thin. I would tend to remove them:

[image]

full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np


sns.set(style="whitegrid", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})
df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/willemvanopstal/c2892e68d6eb94194acd371e49d949bd/raw/642c4261198f0cacdf32aad21aebca5953c6cd75/stats_together_data.csv', delimiter=';')
df.loc[df["aandeel"]==0,"aandeel"]=np.nan

# Initialize the FacetGrid object
pal = sns.color_palette("Set2")
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="process", hue="process", aspect=10, height=0.6, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.lineplot, "region", "aandeel", clip_on=False, alpha=1, lw=1.5)
g.map(plt.fill_between, "region", "aandeel", interpolate=True)
#g.map(sns.lineplot, "region", "aandeel", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2)


# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)


g.map(label, "region")

# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.set(xticks=df.region[0::1])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)

plt.show()
```